# iOS phonegap 2.3 No dmg file for cordovaframework?

Tags: ios, cordova

Currently i am trying to use latest phonegap package of version 2.3.0 , created the cordova project using create script, this created the cordova project, but its adding whole code of cordova inside the project , this is increasing my code size and may be build size also.My question is where i can find an dmg file to install cordova.how to install cordova using phonegap 2.3.0 package. so that i can use it as framework inside my xcode project, as it was their in below 2.0 versions (phone gap).

Comment: It actually creates a reference to the cordova project, which is only stored once on your machine. It does not significantly increase code or build size.

Answer (score 5):

since versión 2.0 there is no .dmg file or installer for Cordova/Phonegap. The newest zip file you download has several folders that correspond to each platform supported by Phonegap.

Each folder has a "create" file (inside the "bin" folder) that is used to create a mobile platform project (for example: ios/bin/create creates an xcode project).

Phonegap website has a pretty good detailed "Getting started guide" for each platform (http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.3.0/guide_getting-started_index.md.html). It may look complicated, but it is pretty simple once you tried and succeed :)

There is no better place to start than this website.